# How to call deferred promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is my code

```
    $scope.login = function(){
        $http.post(URL+'auth/login', {email:'dummy@gmail.com', password:'password'}).then(function(r){
            locker.put('token', r.data.token);

            console.log(locker.get('token'));
        });
    };


    $scope.one = function(){
        IngredientService.ingredients().then(function (response) {
            var data = response.data;
            locker.put('token', response.headers('Authorization').split(" ")[1]);

            console.log(locker.get('token'));
        });
    };

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = deferred.promise;

    promise = promise.then($scope.login()).then($scope.one());
```

I want to login(), when has finish, i want to execute one().

but why my one() has began run before login() has done?

this made error because one() need token from login()

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have two different controller here..i.e. one for login lets say
**loginController** and other to execute one() lets say **homeController**

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('loginController',function($scope){
        $scope.login = function(){
        $http.post(URL+'auth/login', {email:'dummy@gmail.com', password:'password'}).then(function(r){
            locker.put('token', r.data.token);

            console.log(locker.get('token'));
        });
    };  
});

app.controller('homeController',function($scope){
        $scope.one = function(){
        IngredientService.ingredients().then(function (response) {
            var data = response.data;
            locker.put('token', response.headers('Authorization').split(" ")[1]);

            console.log(locker.get('token'));
        });
    };
});
```

so once Login is done token will be saved and then one() can be called as bothe the functions are in different controller assuming you have dedicated view for login.

Hope you are calling $scope.login() method somewhere

**OR**

try below :

```
$scope.login = function(){
        $http.post(URL+'auth/login', {email:'dummy@gmail.com', password:'password'}).then(function(r){
            locker.put('token', r.data.token);

            console.log(locker.get('token'));
           $scope.one();
        });
    };


    $scope.one = function(){
        IngredientService.ingredients().then(function (response) {
            var data = response.data;
            locker.put('token', response.headers('Authorization').split(" ")[1]);

            console.log(locker.get('token'));
        });
    };
```

Comment: Ideally you should have two different controllers for two views ..here in ur case u have login view and some other view..so having 2 controllers make sense ...plz upvote it if it helps u

Comment: on home controller how can i call $scope.one().then($scope.one).then($scope.one); ? the point of my question is how i can call async 1st then 2nd then 3rd

Comment: What I thought you have Login view and then once login you set token you redirect to some other view having HomeController using ngRoute or UiRoute where you have one() method define and you will be able to call one() method from that view as you are already logged in and Token is set. Why do you need to use promise in this case. Please correct me is I am Worng.

Comment: because thats server refresh token every request

Answer (score 0):

I think your login and one should never be called, because the "promise" will never be resolved.

You should do like below, please notice $scope.login should return a promise and then it can be chained with "then".

```
 $scope.login = function(){
        return $http.post(URL+'auth/login', {email:'dummy@gmail.com', password:'password'}).then(function(r){
            locker.put('token', r.data.token);

            console.log(locker.get('token'));
        });
    };


    $scope.one = function(){
        IngredientService.ingredients().then(function (response) {
            var data = response.data;
            locker.put('token', response.headers('Authorization').split(" ")[1]);

            console.log(locker.get('token'));
        });
    };

    $scope.login().then($scope.one);
```

Comment: hi ron, how about if i want to call and add antoher function, let say, $scope.login().then($scope.one).then($scope.one); 
can u give me an example? 
this is error because the 3rd function has been call before 2nd function has done ?

Comment: The point is the function in then has to return a promise if it is async, then the next then can execute the function after the previous promise is resolved. the reason the third one called before the 2nd one is because you miss "return" in the $scope.one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your login function doesn't return a promise. Whenever you return anything besides a promise the next function will run immediately.

Try modifying your login function to return the service call instead.

```
$scope.login = function(){
    $http.post(URL+'auth/login', {email:'dummy@gmail.com', password:'password'}).then(function(r){
        locker.put('token', r.data.token);

        console.log(locker.get('token'));
        return IngredientService.ingredients();
    });
};
```

Then make your call to kick off the chain like this:

```
$scope.login().then(function(response) {
  var data = response.data;
  locker.put('token', response.headers('Authorization').split(" ")[1]);

  console.log(locker.get('token'));
})
```

Check out this article on promises and chaining:

https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angularjs-promises